# create Android boot animation for TextView

Tags: android, android-animation, textview

Is it possible to create the same Android 2.2 boot animation for a TextView (using xml or programatically) ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try Frame Animation.
Try animating each letter individually, and repeating them.

[Here is a tutorial, hope this helps you:](http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/05/android-tutorial-animation-frame-by.html)